# Visual basic 2010 Error

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting an error on fee.ToString("C") when trying to run the code.  The error I keep getting is Value of type 'String'cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox'.  Not sure what I am doing wrong any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.  My code is below.

```
    Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

    Try
        Dim bailInt As Integer
        Dim collItem As String

        Dim fee As Decimal = CDec(0.0)

        'Convert input to values
        bailInt = Integer.Parse(bailAmountTextBox.Text)
        collItem = collateralTextBox.Text

        'Calculate 10% fee on bail amount
        fee = CDec(0.1 * bailInt)

        'Display Messagebox with fee amount
        amountDueTextBox = fee.ToString("C")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Must be numeric data", "Bad Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        With bailAmountTextBox
            .Focus()
            .SelectAll()
        End With

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amountDueTextBox.Text = fee.ToString("C")` try this. Your trying to assign a textbox to a string.

Comment: Thanks can't believe I missed that.